# Add string list in Castle Windsor using xml/app.config

Tags: xml, string, list, app-config, castle-windsor

I need your help configurating a string list in Castle Windsor by using xml/app.config.

My TestConfig.cs looks like this:

```
[Convertible]
public class TestConfig
{     
    public string Test{ get; set; }                  

    public IList<string> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

I configurated my app.config with a list:

```
<item>
  <Test>text</Test>
  <TestList>
     <list>
       <item>TestListItem1</item>
       <item>TestListItem2</item>
       <item>TestListItem3</item>
     </list>
  </TestList>
</item>
```

I also tried to configure my app.config with an array:

```
<item>
  <Test>text</Test>
  <TestList>
     <array>
       <item>TestListItem1</item>
       <item>TestListItem2</item>
       <item>TestListItem3</item>
     </array>
  </TestList>
</item>
```

But in both cases my "TestList" is null.

The variable "Test" is working fine and has the value "Text".

Do you have any tips for me what I can do? Thanks.

best regards
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your component parameters

```
<parameters>
    <Test>text</Test>
    <TestList>
        <list>
            <item>TestListItem1</item>
            <item>TestListItem2</item>
            <item>TestListItem3</item>
        </list>
    </TestList>
</parameters>
```

Check docs castle windsor: [XML Inline Parameters](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/xml-inline-parameters.md)

Comment: With the snippet above or do you've found another solution?

Comment: it's not working when I want to use this list in another list item. So when I have a list with items and one of these items includes another string list then it's not working. I don't know if this should work too.

Comment: Well you have to create a component for both items. One for the parent containing N childs and one component for the child containing N items. Then it should work

Comment: with your above snippet it's working. Ok thanks for the info concerning the N childs.